# Multiple issues with Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) Terminal (Not getting Context menu)

Tags: unity, xterm

Ubuntu noob here.

Used Crouton to install Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) over my Chromebook.

While I am enjoying the OS, I am not so pleased with how the terminal looks.

The terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) default view is very simplistic and I am not able to change it.

1. The font size is small (Crtl + Mouse click changes font size only
   for that session. Doesn't change the default font size)
2. I have read multiple articles and tried multiple suggestions but
   could not figure out how to copy-paste to and from the terminal
   window
3. I am not able to find the menu bar in the terminal window....have
   hovered the mouse everywhere and could not find it. It just says
   Xterm.
4. The text display in the terminal window is all white. Couldn't
   figure out how to make the 'user@localhost:-$' bold and different
   color, while the commands typed are different color.

These issues have been there from the time I installed Ubuntu on top of Chrome OS.

Have browsed many forums, but no luck.

Also tried wiping out and reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times. Still, no luck.

Any help....much appreciated.

EDIT:
I guess my whole issue can be summed up as "Not getting context menu in the terminal" (thanks to user Zwets)

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the terminal, click *Preferences*. All your questions can be answered by changing settings in the dialog that shows up.

BTW: reinstall Ubuntu to fix this issue? I'd stay away from wherever that was proposed as a solution. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have tried that. Nothing happens when I right-click on the terminal :(

Comment: As a long-time Windows user, 'reinstalling' or 'rebooting' to fix any issue have become part of my intuition. I am trying to break out of that :).

Comment: Then I suggest editing your question, as the real issue seems to be that you do not get a context menu in the terminal.